# Unable to find circular reference in custom made formula for excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Ok, so I'm completely unable to understand why there is a circular refence, or why the function is being called again in the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Enum rc
    rc1 = 2
    rl1 = 2
    rcwork = 10 ' Has to be an even number, it's the column index where the 'Work Hours' column is
End Enum

    Public Function WorkHours(currentRow As Long) As Variant
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastCol As Long, lastColTrue As Long ' ,lastRow As Long
    Dim workTime As Variant
    Dim conditionMissingExit As Boolean, conditionMissingEntry As Boolean, conditionMissingEntryExit As Boolean
    
    Application.Volatile
    'Init values
    conditionMissingExit = False
    conditionMissingEntry = False
    i = currentRow
    lastCol = CurrentMonth.Cells(i, rc1).End(xlToRight).Column
    lastColTrue = CurrentMonth.Cells(i, rcwork).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    If lastCol = rcwork And lastColTrue >= rc1 Then
        lastCol = lastColTrue
    ElseIf lastCol = rcwork And lastColTrue < rl1 And CurrentMonth.Cells(i, rc1 + 1) = "" Then
        lastCol = rc1 + 1
    ElseIf lastCol = rcwork And CurrentMonth.Cells(i, rcwork - 2) <> "" Then
        lastCol = rcwork - 1
    End If
    
    If lastColTrue = lastCol Then
        
        lastCol = lastColTrue
        
    Else
        
        If lastColTrue = 1 And CurrentMonth.Cells(i, rc1).Value = "" Then
    
            workTime = ""
            GoTo SafeExit
    
        End If
        
        For j = lastCol To lastColTrue
            
            If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
            
                workTime = "Invalid Entry at cell (" & i & "," & ColIndexToLetter(j) & ")"
                GoTo SafeExit
                
            End If
            
            If CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j).Value = "" And (j Mod 2 = 0) Then
                
                conditionMissingEntry = True
                
                If conditionMissingEntry Then
                    
                    If CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = "" And Not ((j + 1) Mod 2 = 0) Then
                        
                        workTime = "Missing entry and exit"
                        GoTo SafeExit
                        
                    Else
                        
                        workTime = "Missing entry"
                        GoTo SafeExit
                        
                    End If
                    
                End If
                
            ElseIf CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j).Value = "" And Not (j Mod 2 = 0) Then
                
                conditionMissingExit = True
                
                If conditionMissingExit Then
                    
                    If CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = "" And ((j + 1) Mod 2 = 0) Then
                        
                        workTime = "Missing entry and exit"
                        GoTo SafeExit
                        
                    Else
                        
                        workTime = "Missing exit"
                        GoTo SafeExit
                        
                    End If
                    
                End If
    
            End If
        
        Next j
        
    End If
    
    For j = rc1 To lastCol Step 2
        
        conditionMissingExit = (Not CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j).Value = "" And CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = "")
        conditionMissingEntry = (CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j).Value = "" And Not CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = "")
        conditionMissingEntryExit = (CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j).Value = "" And CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = "")
        
        If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
            
            workTime = "Invalid Entry at cell (" & i & "," & ColIndexToLetter(j) & ")"
            Exit For
            
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, j + 1).Value) Then
            
            workTime = "Invalid Entry at cell (" & i & "," & ColIndexToLetter(j + 1) & ")"
            Exit For
            
        End If
        
        If Not conditionMissingExit And Not conditionMissingEntry And Not conditionMissingEntryExit Then
            
            workTime = workTime + DateDiff("n", CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j).Value, CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j + 1).Value) / 60
            
        ElseIf conditionMissingEntry Then
            
            workTime = "Missing entry"
            Exit For
            
        ElseIf conditionMissingExit Then
            
            If CurrentMonth.Cells(i, j + 2).Value = "" And j + 2 <= lastCol Then
                
                workTime = "Missing entry and exit"
                Exit For
                
            Else
                
                workTime = "Missing exit"
                Exit For
                
            End If
            
        ElseIf conditionMissingEntryExit Then
            
            workTime = "Missing entry and exit"
            Exit For
            
        End If
        
    Next j
    
    SafeExit:
    
    WorkHours = workTime
    
    End Function

Public Function ColIndexToLetter(ColIndex As Long) As String

'This function returns the a String corresponding to the letter associated to the column of index ColIndex

Dim CellAddress As String

CellAddress = Cells(1, ColIndex).Address
ColIndexToLetter = Split(CellAddress, "$")(1)

End Function
```

[image: This is the workbook for better understanding]

The formula on cell J2 is:

```
=WorkHours(2)
```

which calls the public function WorkHours

I do not understand what is going on because the macro-formula works , not perfectly, because the function keeps calling itself for some reason when I fill the other cells, it will give the circular error only when I fill the H column cell without filling also the I column cell (See image below)
[image]

Anyway the main problem here is that the function keeps being called for the same row several times, and I do not know why.

**UPDATE:**

Thank you Tim Williams and Toddleson for taking your time to look at my problem.
Tim, following your advice I modified the WorkHours function like this:

```
Public Function WorkHours(currentRow As Long) As Variant

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastCol As Long, lastColTrue As Long ' ,lastRow As Long
Dim workTime As Variant
Dim conditionMissingExit As Boolean, conditionMissingEntry As Boolean, conditionMissingEntryExit As Boolean

Application.Volatile
Debug.Print Application.Caller.Address

End Function
```

The formula is present only on cell J2 and it's being called like this:

```
=WorkHours(2)
```

So that no reference at all to any cell is inputed into the formula.
After that as you can see from the code of the function, the is no cell reading whatsoever.

Now the output in the immediate window is:

```
$J$2
```

Meaning the function is being called only once...

I need to analyse in my previous code what is reading/accessing the calling cell...

Anyway, thank you very much Tim Williams, I didn't know that reading the calling cell would cause this behaviour as it's the first time I use application.volatile

Comment: Volatile means that the formula asks to be recalculated when there are **any** sheet changes. So these cells would each be recalculated during every sheet recalculation. Try removing the line `Application.Volatile`, maybe the behavior was causing unintended problems.

Comment: You need to make sure your function never tries to read the value of the cell it's in.  If you need to know which cell that is, you can use either `Application.Caller` or `Application.ThisCell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your function never tries to read the value of the cell it's in. If you need to know which cell that is, you can use either `Application.Caller` or `Application.ThisCell`

Here's an example to illustrate:

```vb
Function Tester()
    
    Dim c As Range, this As Range, rw As Range
    
    Set this = Application.ThisCell 'the cell with the formula (in this case in Col H)
    
    'Get a range on the same row as the formula, first 20 cells (so that includes the cell with the formula)
    'Note you don't really need the `currentRow` parameter since you can use `ThisCell.Row`
    Set rw = this.Parent.Cells(this.Row, "A").Resize(1, 20)
    
    'This loop will cause a circular reference error as it tries to read from `this`
    '  which triggers the UDF again, etc etc
    For Each c In rw.Cells
        Debug.Print c.Value
    Next c
    
    'this loop avoids the error by not reading from `this`
    For Each c In rw.Cells
        If c.Column <> this.Column Then 'skip the cell with the formula
            Debug.Print c.Value
        End If
    Next c
    
End Function
```